# Node (server) and Dojo (client): where to store the username client-side?

Tags: node.js, authentication, dojo

I am writing a simple application. I wrote the login/password screens, which simply set a session variable:

```
if( docs.password == req.body.password ) {
   errors.push({ field:'password', message: 'Password Match!', mustChange: false } );
   res.json( { response: 'OK' } , 200);
   req.session.loggedIn = true;
   req.session.login = req.body.login;
```

Once Login goes through, the client is redirected to the actual application (as per normal). However, at that point the **client** no longer knows what login name they used to login! (I am talking about the Javascript that runs in the browser)

As you can see, I am saving the user name in the session. However, when the client loads the "application" HTML page, they don't have their own login name as it's a brand new page with brand new Javascript (which is unaware of what username they used to login a moment earlier).

I *could* embed it somewhere in the page's HTML (somewhere like a global JS variable in the page's body?) since it's in the session, but...

How is this "normally" done? What's a good pattern to go about this?

Merc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In express 3 this is how to properly do it.
https://github.com/dotcloud/express-on-dotcloud/blob/master/app/app.js#L65

You setup a middle that send the session to all the routes's template.

Comment: I clarified my question -- sorry. The point is to get the Javascript to know the username

Comment: Ah, I just "got" your question: you place the session in the response object, so that template engines have it! OK, but I still need to print it somehow in the page... right?

Comment: This is because I did not got you question. You need a template engine. Use ejs if you want something really close to html (https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/ejs/index.js)